# Add more Stack Exchange pages to Offtopic-Flag

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to add more Stack Exchange subpages to redirect to, if the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow?

The motivation for that question is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106589/do-i-have-to-create-new-software-tool-to-write-journal-paper), which I rather would recommend for [academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) or [scicomp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), but not for Stack Overflow. Or is there another reason for not having those pages available?